# Disabling package install feature from R GUI and RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

We have our R and RStudio Desktop running on individual users Windows 7 desktops and all the users are getting the required packages from our local R package repository. No, i am trying to see if there is a way to block users from access to external CRAN repository mirrors.

Editing "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\etc\repositories" files and making CRAN point to our local repository URL is helpful but this will only work as long as users are not trying to exercise R GUI Packages-> install packages or set CRAN mirrors options.(CRAN variable is getting over ridden as and when R GUI options are exercised. )

This is the reason i am truing to see if there is a way to disable R GUI and/ or R Studio Package install GUI options?

I didnt find any help how to do it on R GUI without modifying the source code, but RStudio seem to have an environment variable which is supposed to disable this option but is not working for me.

As per this [link](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/210990438-Disabling-RStudio-Features%22) setting "RSTUDIO_DISABLE_PACKAGES" environment variable should do the trick but setting this variable to 1 on below locations doesnt do anything.

C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\etc\Renviron.site
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\etc\x64.Renviron.x64

Also, I found below text on RStudio admin guide but don't know what are the equivalent files and folders for windows environment and whether or not this is applicable to RStudio desktop

/etc/rstudio/rsession.conf
allow-package-installation=0